# How to insert set of key value pair in MongoDB collection?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following structure in hash table in the form of nested key/value pairs. Let's say I have a collection in MongoDB named structure. The key here is the NAME. How do I insert the key/value pairs inside FIELDS: { key: 'value', key: 'value' } into this structure collection?

```
  var input 4 = {   
{ OBJ_TYPE: 'Paris',    
  NAME: 'Paris.Name,
  FIELDS:
  { UNAME: 'STRING', // key is NAME, value is STRING
   DESC: 'STRING' // key is DESC, value is STRING
  }
} 


{ OBJ_TYPE: 'London', 
  NAME: 'London.Name,  
   FIELDS:
    { UNAME: 'STRING',
     DESC: 'STRING'
   }
}

 { OBJ_TYPE: 'X',
    NAME: 'X.XName,
    FIELDS:
   { UNAME: 'STRING',
     DESC: 'STRING'
   }
 }
```

### }

```
 var test = Message.init(input4);
 var hashTable = test.hash_table;

if(hashTable["OBJECT_TYPE"] == "FEED"){
   for(var key in hashTable){
          if(key == "FIELDS"){
                 var keyHashTable = hashTable[key];
                 for(var column in keyHashTable){
                       var key;
                       var columns = new Array();
                       if(column == "NAME"){
                              key = column;
                              print("key"+key);
                       }else{
                              print("column"+column);
                       }

           structure.update(
                         {key:NAME},
                        *{$set:{/*some dynamic variable or logic here */ }},*
                        {upsert:true},
                        function(err,data){
                              if (err){
                              console.log(err);
                           }else{
                               //console.log("Successfully upserted");
                        }
                    });
```

I want MongoDB to store like this.

```
NAME(key)     | UNAME i.e. FIELDS 1  |  DESC i.e. FIELDS 2 |
___________________________________________________________|
Paris.Name    |                      |                     |
London.Name   |                      |                     | 
X.Xname       |                      |                     |
```

Comment: So what is the intended structure of the target collection? Also not really clear if you are intending to "update" documents in an existing collection or create a new collection or new documents. Certainly a hardcoded `{ "key": null }` query is just going to keep matching the same document, so that itself makes you intent unclear. Can you edit to clarify please?

Comment: @NeilLunn I just added the intent structure of the target collection. I would like to insert if the key does not exist. I read that if I use update with {upsert:true}, it check if the key exists, if it exists then it updates else if the key does not exist, it inserts.